# Rest fb: reactions and aliasing fields

Tags: facebook, restfb

I'm using Restfb and want get general information about posts on a certain page. I'm wondering if there is way to get the summary that include total_count for each reaction ? Something like :

"summary": {
      "total_count": 51,
      "total_count_HAHA":23,
      "total_count_LOVE":28,
      "viewer_reaction": "NONE"
    }

I can only retrieve the total_count with the documentation provided.
I tried to search for solutions online and the commonly used one (in other APIs) is the usage of Aliasing fields. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any info about aliasing in Restfb. Any idea about how to overcome this challenge? :-)

Answer (score 0):

i'm new to Restfb and working on a similar case. I've found this (credit to this guy [here](http://marjavamitjava.com/fetch-facebook-reactions-posts/))

```
JsonObject obj= facebookClient.fetchObject(post.getId(),JsonObject.class,
                    Parameter.with("fields",
                            "reactions.type(LOVE).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(reactions_love),"+
                                    "reactions.type(WOW).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(reactions_wow),"+
                                    "reactions.type(HAHA).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(reactions_haha),"+
                                    "reactions.type(LIKE).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(reactions_like),"+
                                    "reactions.type(ANGRY).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(reactions_angry),"+
                                    "reactions.type(SAD).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(reactions_sad)"));
```

It will return you this response (in this example there were no reactions on the post). Your facebook client should be configured to use v2.6 of the graph API 
Hope this helps :)

```
{"reactions_haha":{"summary":{"total_count":0},"data":[]},"reactions_angry":{"summary":{"total_count":0},"data":[]},"reactions_sad":{"summary":{"total_count":0},"data":[]},"reactions_like":{"summary":{"total_count":0},"data":[]},"id":"id_of_post","reactions_love":{"summary":{"total_count":0},"data":[]},"reactions_wow":{"summary":{"total_count":0},"data":[]}}
```

Comment: If you extend the `Post` type and add additional fields for `reactions_wow` and so on using the java type `Reactions`, you can make use of some RestFB features and simply access these values. `JsonObject` is okay, but accessing the `total_count` values is not that beautiful :)